# How do I remove Jquery Uncaught Syntax Error

Tags: jquery

I have error in my code. I am new to jquery. it says uncaught syntax error. Please help. I have tries adding and removing short brackets and semicolons. I do not know What I am doing wrong.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>              
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        var name= $("#username").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'add_user.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{username:name},
            success:function(response) {
                var msg = "";
                if(response == 1) {
                    msg = "Logged into system successfully.!";
                    $("#message").html(msg);                    
                    $("#message").addClass("alert alert-success");
                }
                else {
                    msg = "Invalid username and password!";
                    $("#message").html(msg);                    
                    $("#message").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                }
            });
        });
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it should. You didn't close with brackets at the end properly. Check these two - `$(document).ready(function() { $("#form").submit(function() {`. At the end, you'll have two closings - `)}; )};`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the bracket:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        var name= $("#username").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'add_user.php',
            type:'post',
            data:{username:name},
            success:function(response) {
                var msg = "";
                if(response == 1) {
                    msg = "Logged into system successfully.!";
                    $("#message").html(msg);                    
                    $("#message").addClass("alert alert-success");
                }
                else {
                    msg = "Invalid username and password!";
                    $("#message").html(msg);                    
                    $("#message").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                }
           }
       });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

One bracket has not been closed. Please check at the end of your code:

```
...
        });
    };
});
</script>
```

You need to change to this:

```
...
        });
    });
});
</script>
```